# react native: Rendering an array of strings and numbers doesn't work

Tags: react-native

In the react native app I'm retrieving some data from my backend and then want to display it to the app user:
when I log the data I can see that I receive it and stored it properly in the state as an object:

```
// console.log("received the data: ", this.state.data) ->
received the data:  Object {      
  "a": 48,
  "b": "2021-03-29T17:11:51Z",
  "c": "",
  "d": false
}
```

But when I try to render that in my view, the screen simply stays empty (no error message):

```
render() {
  // let me check, if the data is really there
    Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => {
                console.log("key: ", key, "- value: ", value)
            })
  // output:
  // key: a - value: 48,
  // key: b - value: 2021-03-29T17:11:51Z,
  // key: c - value: ,
  // key:d - value: false

    return (
            <View>
                {Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => {
                    return <View key={key}><Text>{value}</Text></View>
                })}
            </View>

    )
}
```

I also tried this, but still I receive an empty screen:

```
render() {
    return (
         { this.state.data.map((items, index) => {
              return (
                  <ul key={index}>
                       {Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
                          return (
                             <li key={key + index}>{key}:{items[key]}</li>
                          )
                       })}
                  </ul>
              )
         })}
   )
}
```

**Edit:** The full component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios';

class SuccessScreen extends React.Component {
    baseURL = "https://my-backend-server-URL.com/data"

    state = {
        data: {},
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startGetData();
    }

startGetData = () => {
        
        axios.get(this.baseUrl)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("got the data: ", response.data)
                this.state.data = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //handle error
                console.log("error getting data: ", err.message)
                return {
                    type: "REGISTER_USER_FAILED",
                    payload: null
                }
            });
    };

    render() {
        console.log("This log will show up")
        return (
            <View>
                {this.state.vehicleData && Object.entries(this.state.vehicleData).map(([key, value]) => {
                    console.log("this log never shows up... key: ", key)   // these logs don't not show up
                    return <View key={key}><Text>{value}</Text></View>
                })}
            </View>

        )
    }
}

export default SuccessScreen;
```

Comment: put a console.log inside `Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => {` just before the `return` that you have, and check if it's there the data. Also, show what `imports` are you using in your component

Comment: I put a console.log just before the return statement, but the log doesn't appear in my logs... I thought it's maybe not possible to call console.log there?

Comment: and I added my imports at the bottom of my post now.

Comment: yes you can, example: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/wncm5ho3/1/  So the data is not in the `this.state.data` that's your problem

Comment: Is it possible that you are mutating state somehow?  This would prevent the component from re-rendering when it should.  Your render method is fine assuming that the data exists.  if @pmiranda's answer doesn't solve this then please include the entire component.

Comment: I added the full component now, should have done that right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for data to be defined, Try this:

```
return (
    <View>
        {this.state.data && Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => {
            return <View key={key}><Text>{value}</Text></View>
        })}
    </View>
```

Edit:

Don't mutate  `this.state.data = response.data` that way, use the setState:

```
 this.setState({ data: response.data });
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do

Comment: Probably a good idea to wait for the data. I tried this, but it seams like it never get's even called. (I added the full component in my post now)

Comment: I edited my answer, you are not setting your state correctly.

Comment: I always forget setState... ok it worked now with `this.setState({ data: response.data });`